# Cohomology and Base Change - Degree 0 Sanity Check

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Both Vakil and Hartshorne describe Cohomology and Base Change in the following way:

> Suppose $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a projective (in Vakil, proper)
>   morphism of Noetherian schemes, $F$ a coherent sheaf on $X$ flat over
>   $Y.$ If the natural map $\phi^i(y): R^if_*(F) \rightarrow H^i(X_y,F_y)$ is surjective, then $\phi^{i-1}(y)$ is also surjective
>   if and only if $R^if_*(F)$ is locally free near $y$.

An important special case would be when $i=0$. I'm nervous about the fact that neither author singles out this special case, and my silly question is: does the hypothesis "$\phi^{-1}(y)$ is surjective" hold vacuously when $i=0$? In other words, is surjectivity of $\phi^0(y)$ enough to conclude local freeness of $f_*F$ near $y$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the posting of this question, Vakil's text has been amended to address this exact issue. Here's the wording of the theorem in the [November 18, 2017 version](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), which is the most recent as of the posting of this answer:

> **28.1.6 Cohomology and Base Change Theorem.** Suppose $\pi:X\to Y$ is proper, $Y$ is locally Noetherian, $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent over $X$ and flat over $Y$, and $\phi_q^p: R^p\pi_*\mathcal{F}\otimes\kappa(q)\to H^p(X_q,\mathcal{F}|_{X_q})$ is surjective. Then the following hold.
>
> (i) There is an open neighborhood $U$ of $q$ such that for any $\psi:Z\to U$, $\phi_Z^p$ is an isomorphism. In particular, $\phi_q^p$ is an isomorphism.
>
> (ii) Furthermore, $\phi_q^{p-1}$ is surjective (hence an isomorphism by (i)) if and only if $R^p\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally free in some open neighborhood of $q$ (or equivalently, $(R^p\pi_*\mathcal{F})_q$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{Y,q}$-module, Exercise 13.7.F). This in turn implies that $h^p$ is constant in an open neighborhood of $q$.
>
> (Proofs of Theorems 28.1.5 and 28.1.6 will be given in §28.2. **Note in (ii) that if $p=0$, $\phi_q^{p-1}$ is automatically surjective, as the codomain of $\phi_q^{-1}$ is $H^{-1}(X_q,\mathcal{F}|_{X_q})$, which is $0$ by definition**.)

(My emphasis added on the final sentence.)